# How do I force TuesPechkin to use the latest version of 'wkhtmltox.dll' (0.12.5)?

Tags: c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

I've downloaded the more recent version of `TuesPechkin` *and* the most recent version of `TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.Win64.dll`.

The version of the latter is 0.12.2. I need to access fixes in 0.12.5.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what I have to do to get `TuesPechkin` to use the latest version of `wkhtmltopdf.dll` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace wkhtmltox_64.dll.gz with lastest version
[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

```
using TuesPechkin.Wkhtmltox.AnyCPU;
...
var converter = PDFHelper.Factory.GetConverter();
var result = converter.Convert(This.Document);
```

If you need anycpu version, check [here](https://github.com/tloy1966/TuesPechkin)